# Whats wrong with my date/timezone using this DateUtil?

Tags: java, datetime, offset

I never seem to have the value that I am expecting. I want to pass in a timezone and get the correct time back and it never seems quite right. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 long timezoneOffset = DateUtil.getTimeZoneOffset(aTimezone);   
        Calendar rangeStart = DateUtil.getCalendarByMillisInTimezone(event.getStartDate().getTimeInMillis() -timezoneOffset , timezone);

Calendar rangeEnd = DateUtil.getCalendarByMillisInTimezone(event.getEndDate().getTimeInMillis()-timezoneOffset,  timezone);
```

Comment: Hi.  What language are you asking about, and where does that function come from?  Searching both Google and GitHub for `getCalendarByMillisInTimezone` returns nothing.  If that's your own code, you'll need to show it to us for us to be able to help you.  Please edit your question to included these details.

Comment: Also you say you aren't getting what you expect - well, what do you pass in, what do you get, and what did you expect?  If you don't tell us, we have no way to help you.  Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Thanks.

Comment: ok sorry, its java. So if I have the time in millisecs and a timezone, I want to get back the time for that timezone handling the offset from UTC time. So I guess the question is what shoud I be using?

Comment: Everything you could need is in the [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/package-summary.html).  But again - there's no way to tell what you're actually doing in the code you provided, because `DateUtil` appears to be of your own creation.  We don't have that code here.

Comment: Even from the first line of code you gave, what is `aTimezone`? Is it a string? some object?  What does `DateUtil.getTimeZoneOffset` do? It could give the *current* offset? or just the *standard* offset by the current rules?  Something else?  (Keep in mind that offset in effect for a time zone depends very much on which point in time you are asking about.)

Comment: Whenever you try to replace the actual time zone information with just the offset, you are effectively ignoring changing offsets (mostly daylight savings time) and changing timezones (which happens more often than you'd think). So from that perspective this is already wrong, but how wrong *exactly* is hard to tell without more code. Can you [edit] your question to include an [mre], please?